# Which checksum-generating command line programs are native to macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, hashing, checksum

[Migrated question from stackoverflow here, because they said it was off-topic.]

I'm looking for a list/an overview of the command-line programs *native* to macOS that let you calculate checksums.

I know of the following:

CRC-32: `/usr/bin/crc32`

MD2: `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -md2` [Note: produces an `unknown option '-md2'` error on my system]

MD4: `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -md4`

MD5: `/sbin/md5` or `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -md5`

MDC-2: `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -mdc2`

RIPEMD-160: `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -ripemd160`

SHA: `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -sha`

SHA-1: `/usr/bin/shasum -a 1` or `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -sha1`

SHA-224: `/usr/bin/shasum -a 224` or `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -sha224`

SHA-256: `/usr/bin/shasum -a 256` or `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -sha256`

SHA-384: `/usr/bin/shasum -a 384` or `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -sha384`

SHA-512: `/usr/bin/shasum -a 512` or `/usr/bin/openssl dgst -sha512`

*Note*: According to the `openssl` [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/dgst.html) BLAKE2B and BLAKE2S can also be calculated, but I haven't managed to do it on macOS, neither with the default `/usr/bin/openssl` nor with the homebrewed version `/usr/local/bin/openssl`.

Those are the ones I know. Any other **native** ways to calculate additional checksums from the command line, e.g. Adler-32, CRC-64, GOST, Whirlpool etc.?

I know you can always install programs like **[rhash](http://rhash.anz.ru)** into `/usr/local/bin`, but I'm trying to look at the native methods first. This can also include scripting your own functions using native *libraries*, like `zlib` for Adler-32.

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for since you already list MD5 (so adding this as a comment rather than an answer): `/sbin/md5`

Comment: You're right, thank you. Added. Also added `openssl` alternatives to `shasum`

Comment: A belated welcome to Super User.  Sorry you're getting bounced around the Stack Exchange, but your question may be considered off-topic here, too.  This site focuses on how to solve a specific problem.  Asking how to calculate a checksum has been asked and answered many times.  However, asking what program you can use to do something, or building a list of alternatives, is off-topic (product recommendation or too broad).  It's a great question, and certainly useful, but I'm not sure there's an on-topic way to ask for what you're looking for.

Comment: OK, I might have a solution for you.  Use a self-answered question, and make the answer community wiki.  The question would be something like "How can I calculate checksums from the command line using a program native to MacOS?", and add that the purpose is to create a canonical reference.  Make your list so far an answer, and make sure it includes a sample command for each, not just a list of programs.  Add a sentence inviting others to contribute, and make it community wiki to encourage that.

Comment: Nah, you do it. I don't have the time.

Answer (score 2):

Sha256 is the default algorithm of openssl.
OpenSSL-1.1.0 has included blake2b and blake2s message digests algorithms. 
You can use this command to see the list of supported algorithms.

```
openssl list --digest-commands
```

If you use latest openssl-1.1.0b ( 29th September,2016 ), you could get this:

```
blake2b512        blake2s256        gost              md4
md5               mdc2              rmd160            sha1
sha224            sha256            sha384            sha512
```

It means that, you can use blake2b or blake2s as usual.

```
openssl dgst -blake2b512 /path/to/file
openssl dgst -blake2s256 /path/to/file
```

Comment: Nitpick: SHA256 is default for `openssl dgst` as of 1.1.0; before that it's MD5.